# innerHTML' of null for the time and class when time changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I keep on getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null on the time where it tells u the day, hour, minute. "timeDiv2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '
';" this the one always being error or when it closing time.it changes to the error or stays at the same line. am i writing it correct?

```js
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/599346900698327146/files/Gifs/OpenLightOff.png';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/599346900698327146/files/Gifs/OpenLightOn.gif';




var now = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var today = weekday[now.getDay()];

var dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();

  
  var suffix = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
var checkTime2 = function() {
  

  var timeDiv2 = document.getElementById('timeDiv2');
  

  //add AM or PM
  

  // add 0 to one digit minutes
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes
  };

  if ((dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 || dayOfWeek == 0 ) && hour >= 6 && hour <= 21) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15

 timeDiv2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src= '+imgArray[1].src+'></center>';
    timeDiv2.className = 'open';
  } 
  
  else if ((dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour >= 6 && hour <= 22){
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
 timeDiv2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src= '+imgArray[1].src+'></center>';
    timeDiv2.className = 'open';
  } 
  
  else {
    if (hour == 0 || hour > 5) {
      hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    }

     timeDiv2.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src= '+imgArray[0].src+' ></center>';
     timeDiv2.className = 'closed';
  }
};

var currentDay = weekday[now.getDay()];
var currentDayID = "." + currentDay; //gets todays weekday and turns it into id
$(currentDayID).toggleClass("today"); //hightlights today in the view hours modal popup


checkTime2();
```

```css
 [id ^="timeDiv"]
 {


  width:100%;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;

  border-radius: 3px;

 /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;*/
  display:block;

  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.day {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.time {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}

.today {
  color: rgb(200, 85, 39);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.closed {

  color: rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.85);

}

.open {
  position:relative;
  color: #27ae60;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="timeDiv2"></div>
```

Comment: Are you including your script before or after the DIV? You don’t show that in the code you pasted.

Comment: jQuery 1.2.3 has been released almost 10 years ago. It is seriously, seriously outdated. Also, why don't you just spare yourself a lot of pain and use MomentJS? Finally, why do you include jQuery, then use `document.getElementById` ?

Comment: Are you putting your JavaScript code before the <body> ?

Comment: place your script inside  DOM ready function. You script is no doubt executing before it reads the element which will then return as null. `$(function(){ //Place Your Script Here });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `timeDiv2` element is part of your DOM, the best chance is that you run the javascript code before the HTML is being completely loaded.

You can fix this by calling the `checkTime2()` function only once the page has completely loaded:

```
$(function() {
    checkTime2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting you manipulate your DOM before it has loaded, try one of the following.

### 1.

Load your script as the last part of your `body`.

### 2.

Use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    /** Your code here... **/
});
```

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading. A very different event load should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page. It is an incredibly popular mistake to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be much more appropriate, so be cautious.

### 3.

If you are using jQuery then,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     /** Your code here... **/
});
```